# SELECT from database date where date is today and multiple

Tags: mysql, sql

There are a method with SQL to SELECT from one database the date records where the date is today and the date is multiple of two years.

For example, i have a table call "list". That table have two column, 'ID' and 'last_date'. One of this record is: ID = '1' and date = '17-03-2015'

I need to select all record where the date is the date on the table + 2 year. For example today the query will return the ID 1.

Thanks to all.

Comment: @ShawnMehan He's looking for a specific date, not a range. And it's MySQL, not T-SQL.

Comment: In terms of writing a query, the *datatype* of the `last_date` column (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `VARCHAR`) is just as important as the *name* of the column. (The example value `'17-03-2015'` is *not* in the standard format for MySQL `DATE`, which is a hint that the column  may not be declared as a `DATE`.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_SUB()` to subtract 2 years from today's date, and compare that to the column.

```
SELECT id
FROM list
WHERE last_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```

This is a little better than @Teja's solution because it only has to do the date arithmetic once, rather than for every row in the table. And if there's an index on the `last_date` column, it will be able to use it to find the rows quickly.

Answer (score 0):

We can write an expression that returns a date value that is exactly two days before today's date:

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 YEAR
```

We can use an expression in the `WHERE` clause of a query.  If the column in the table we want to check is defined as `DATE` datatype:

```
 SELECT t.id
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.mydatecol = DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 YEAR
```

If it's defined as a `DATETIME`, the normal pattern would be range check

```
 SELECT t.id
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.mydatecol >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 YEAR 
    AND t.mydatecol  < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 YEAR + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If the column is stored as a VARCHAR in a non-canonical format e.g. DD-MM-YYYY then we could either attempt to convert that to a DATE using STR_TO_DATE (which we don't like to do because the query can't make effective use of a index), or we could convert our generated date value into the required string format for an equality comparison:

```
 SELECT t.id
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.ddmmyyyy = DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 YEAR,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

That would get us exact match to '17-03-2015',  but not to '17-3-2015'. And we have to do equality test or IN list,  we can't do range check, because the value stored in the column isn't canonical.

---

If we need to look for multiple dates... today, two years ago, four years ago, six years ago, ...   we can generate a list of dates and perform a join operation. (Assuming that mydatecol is defined as DATETIME...)

```
 SELECT t.id
   FROM ( SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 YEAR AS dt
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -4 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -6 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -8 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -10 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -12 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -14 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -16 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -18 YEAR
          UNION ALL SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -20 YEAR
        ) l
   JOIN mytable t
  WHERE t.mydatecol >= l.dt + INTERVAL 0 DAY
    AND t.mydatecol <  l.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```